# Can't flash ESP32 S3 Devkit

Tags: microcontroller, esp32

I just received my ESP32 S3 and I wanted to follow the [documentation](https://github.com/espressif/vscode-esp-idf-extension/blob/master/README.md#Prerequisites), so I installed the visual studio code extension "Espressif IDF". There was a prompt to use the express installation and I clicked it. Then I pressed F1 and pasted "ESP-IDF: Show Examples Projects" and selected "Blink". I then clicked the port button in the bottom left corner to choose the only COM port to my esp32s3. It was plugged into the usb micro port labeled "USB". I then pressed F1 and pasted "ESP-IDF: Set Espressif device target" to choose my "esp32s3" and then the "onboard USB" option. I also F1 pasted "ESP-IDF: Select OpenOCD Board Configuration" and selected "esp32 s3". The next step would be to build, so I clicked bottom build icon. Then I clicked the flash button, but I got a popup saying that "OpenOCD has not started, Would you like to start it?"

But after I click yes or no, I get the error message

```
Licensed under GNU GPL v2
For bug reports, read
    http://openocd.org/doc/doxygen/bugs.html

C:\Users\acer\.espressif\tools\openocd-esp32\v0.12.0-esp32-20230419\openocd-esp32\bin\openocd.exe

[OpenOCD]
Open On-Chip Debugger v0.12.0-esp32-20230419 (2023-04-18-22:02)
Licensed under GNU GPL v2
For bug reports, read
    http://openocd.org/doc/doxygen/bugs.html

[OpenOCD]
debug_level: 2
Info : only one transport option; autoselecting 'jtag'
Info : esp_usb_jtag: VID set to 0x303a and PID to 0x1001
Info : esp_usb_jtag: capabilities descriptor set to 0x2000

[OpenOCD]
Warn : Transport "jtag" was already selected

[OpenOCD]
Info : Listeni
[OpenOCD]
ng on port 6666 for tcl connections
Info : Listening on port 4444 for telnet connections

[OpenOCD]
❌ Error: esp_usb_jtag: could not find or open device!

[OpenOCD]
❌ C:\Users\acer\.espressif\tools\openocd-esp32\v0.12.0-esp32-20230419/openocd-esp32/share/openocd/scripts/target/esp_common.cfg:4: Error: 
at file "C:\Users\acer\.espressif\tools\openocd-esp32\v0.12.0-esp32-20230419/openocd-esp32/share/openocd/scripts/target/esp_common.cfg", line 4

[OpenOCD]
[Stopped] : OpenOCD Server
[Flash]
Can't perform JTag flash, because OpenOCD server is not running!
```

I would like to flash this blink project to my microcontroller. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I don't have any experience with ESP32, but it looks like the usb-to-jtag interface is responding on the USB side (you're getting version numbers for the debugger chip), but when it tries to communicate with the processor over JTAG it is getting no reply. Most likely option (assuming no hardware faults) is that the processor isn't powered (is there a method of powering up the board that you may have missed?), or the clock speed of the JTAG is incorrect.

Comment: Has your board got usb->jtag or the usual usb->serial interface?  No debugging on the latter - you can only load the code and use the esp32 uart.

Comment: @Entropy, It actually already has a "Blink" sketch on it. Apparently it came with it and as soon as I powered it on the first time, it started blinking. Maybe the speed of the JTAG is incorrect, I will look into it now.

Comment: @kartman, So I can only load with UART? I will look into that. I thought I had tried the UART port before, but I think that I didn't switch some setting over.

Comment: @kartman, Thank you. Flashing with UART did the trick. When I tried to flash it earlier with the UART port on my ESP32S3, I still had it in JTAG mode or whatever. If fact, there was no UART option for me. I had to search "IDF" in the Visual Studio Code Command Palette in order to find the option to select the upload type. It then came up with UART as an option.
Once again, Thank You.